# Why Cypress service is failing?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, cypress, gitlab-ci.yml

Below is my pipeline on which I'm trying to get Cypress job to run tests against
Nginx service (which points to the main app) which is built at the `build` stage
The below is based on official template from here https://gitlab.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-docker-gitlab/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml
:

```
image: docker:stable

services: 
   - docker:dind

stages: 
   - build
   - test

cache:
   key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
   paths:      
      - .npm    
      - cache/Cypress                                      
      - node_modules                                                             

job:                              
   stage: build                                           
   script:                                                                      
     - export REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL=http://127.0.0.1
     - apk add --update --no-cache gcc g++ make python2 python2-dev py-pip python3-dev docker-compose npm
     - docker-compose up -d --build

e2e:                                                                           
   image: cypress/included:9.1.1                                                
   stage: test
   script:
      - export CYPRESS_VIDEO=false            
      - export CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://nginx:80                                   
      - npm i randomstring
      - $(npm bin)/cypress run -t -v $PWD/e2e -w /e2e -e CYPRESS_VIDEO -e CYPRESS_baseUrl --network testdriven_default
      - docker-compose down
```

Error output:

```
Cypress encountered an error while parsing the argument config
You passed: if [ -x /usr/local/bin/bash ]; then
    exec /usr/local/bin/bash 
elif [ -x /usr/bin/bash ]; then
    exec /usr/bin/bash 
elif [ -x /bin/bash ]; then
    exec /bin/bash 
elif [ -x /usr/local/bin/sh ]; then
    exec /usr/local/bin/sh 
elif [ -x /usr/bin/sh ]; then
    exec /usr/bin/sh 
elif [ -x /bin/sh ]; then
    exec /bin/sh 
elif [ -x /busybox/sh ]; then
    exec /busybox/sh 
else
    echo shell not found
    exit 1
fi
The error was: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
```

What is wrong with this set up ?

Answer (score 2):

From @jparkrr on GitHub : https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images/issues/300#issuecomment-626324350

> I had the same problem. You can specify entrypoint: [""] for the image in .gitlab-ci.yml.
>
> Read more about it here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#overriding-the-entrypoint-of-an-image

In your case :

```
e2e:
   image:
      name: cypress/included:9.1.1
      entrypoint: [""]
```